# What is memory -cache in memory plugin of collectd?

Tags: graphite, collectd

In the memory plugin of collectd , there are four attributes -

1. Memory used
2. Memory Free
3. Memory buffer
4. Memory cache

What does each of them mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain it more simple :

1. **Memory Used** is memory that you're using for any running process.
2. **Memory Free** is memory that doesn't do anything useful. It is normal that the operating system puts that memory to use.
3. **Memory Buffer** is a buffer that holding every single piece of data that is transmitted from one storage location to another (like when using a circular buffer in audio processing). A buffer allows just that - a "buffer" of data before and after your current position in the data stream.
4. **Memory Cache** is a partial data that is cached so that the remaining data can be transferred without any performance penalty. In this context, the cache only "pre-fetches" a small amount of data (depending on the transfer rates, cache sizes, etc...).

Comment: How do this metrics correspond to top utility per process VIRT, RES?